# exact filtering on ALL option in angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

When i use the exact filtering, filtering works good but not working on populating ALL options when ALL selected.

```
                    field: '4',
                    suppressRemoveSort: true,
                    enableColumnMenu: false,
                    filter: {
                        term: ' ',
                        type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
                        condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT,
                        selectOptions: [{value:' ',label:'ALL'}, {value:'NONE', label:'NONE'}, {value:'CAT', label:'CAT'}]
                    },
```

How should i get all the results when ALL selected? Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Did you find useful the answer?

Comment: No, I have used a different condition to slove my problem.

Comment: You should answer your own question in order to help someone with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own sorting algorithm. Look at the following documentation: [Sorting ui-grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Sorting)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with below snippet

```
field: '4',
                suppressRemoveSort: true,
                enableColumnMenu: false,
                filter: {
                    term: ' ',
                    type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
                    condition: uiGridConstants.filter.ENDS_WITH,
                    selectOptions: [{value:' ',label:'ALL'}, {value:'NONE', label:'NONE'}, {value:'CAT', label:'CAT'}]
                },
```